# Nuget package restore ERROR

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, microservices, nuget-package

We created one rest client application and pushed it to nuget with version 1.0.0 and used it in one of our Micro Services and then recently we updated our Rest client application with new version 1.1.0 and tried to update it in our Micro services using nuget package restore.

Now we got the latest version of our RestClient application dll ie Project.json file got updated with my latest version 1.1.0. But now when i try to build the application i am getting error for namespace not found for restclient

When i checked project.json its already updated with my new version 1.1.0

NOTE: I am using .net core

Why i am not getting reference to my latest RestClient dll (1.1.0) in my MicroServices?

Is there any work around for it?

One work around i did is i deleted Project.json.lock files and i tried to restore again. But no luck

Comment: `project.json`? That's obsolete. Migrate to Visual Studio 2017 please.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, but for us vs2017 update not started yet. but for the time being i need to stick on to this..

Comment: “I need to stick on to this” is just the wrong way. Either you go the right way, or nobody would be able to help.

Comment: @LexLi So it was working fine with our older version of RestClient dll.  So you are saying that i wont be able to get a version update unless and untill i switch to vs2017? Also can you you elaborate little bit about the relation between project.json and nuget package upgrade?

Comment: You are using obsolete things, so no matter what works or not you are fully on your own. If you don't want to migrate, then there is nothing more to talk about.

Comment: @LexLi lets see if there is someone who already faced this same type of issue or with more clear answer to my question. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone comes across to this situation, what happen to me is when i build the new package with release mode, the new dll file was not getting attached. So when i check the .nupkg(change its file type to zip, extract and see) file, that .dll file was missing. That was the cause. So i tried once again and it double checked and then pushed to nuget. and tried to restore the package in project.json file by changing the version number, and the problem got resolved.

@LexLi this is the solution which i was looking for.